# Spring Cloud Kubernetes reads other configuration files under the namespace

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Spring Cloud Kubernetes reads other configuration files under the namespace

**Version：**

springboot:2.2.8.RELEASE

spring-cloud-kubernetes: 1.1.6.RELEASE

I would like to extract part of the public configuration files, such as:

1. jdbc.yaml
2. redis.yaml
3. elasticsearch.yaml

**Use it with a direct reference**

**application:**

```json
server:
  port: 8011
feign:
  demo2:
    name: k8s-demo2-service
    url:
    path:
spring:
  application:
    name: k8s-demo1
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      reload:
        enabled: true
      ribbon:
        mode: service
      config:
        name: k8s-demo1
        namespace: demo-namespace
        sources:
          - name: jdbc-default-name
```

**configMap-message**

```json
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: k8s-demo1
  namespace: demo-namespace
data:
  bean.value: 'Testing reload! Message from backend is: %s <br/> Services : %s'
```

**jdbc-default-name.yml**

```json
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jdbc-default-name
  namespace: demo-namespace
data:
  tc.config.test.value: Testing
```

OR

```json
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: jdbc-default-name
  namespace: demo-namespace
data:
  jdbc-default-name.properties: |-
    tc.config.test.value: Testing
```

**My java code:**

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tc.config.test")
public class ValueConfig {

    private String value;
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/demo1"})
public class DemoConfigMapController {

    @Autowired
    private ValueConfig valueConfig;

    @GetMapping({"/testvalue"})
    public String testvalue() {
        return valueConfig.getValue();
    }
}
```

`configMap-message` configMap is normal work.**but jdbc-default-name don't work,Data not available**

Is there something wrong with my thinking? Or am I writing it wrong?

In addition, must `metadata.name` be the same as `application.name`?

Comment: Writing in bootstrap.yml is valid and may depend on the boot loading order。